# Install MySQL Community 5.6.14 in Passive mode using batch file (on win7)

Tags: mysql, installation, passive-mode

I'm trying to install MySQL Community 5.6.14 in Passive mode using a batch file.

First of all "MySQLInstaller" is unable to install MySQL in passive or quiet mode and user has to complete the installation wizard manually!

Does MySQL Community 5.6.14 support passive (or quiet) mode?!

Secondly, I have tested MySQLInstallerConsole examples but I couldn't find a correct combination of parameters !!!

Batch File Content:

```
@Echo off

echo Installing MysqlInstaller....

msiexec /i "c:\mysql\mysql.msi" /passive

cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Installer

echo Config MysqlServer....

MySQLInstallerConsole --type=developer --action=install --product=* --config=mysql-server-5.6.14-win32:passwd=apassword

echo Finished !

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the help by typing:

```
MySQLInstallerConsole.exe install
```

try this:

```
MySQLInstallerConsole.exe install server;5.6.17:*:port=3306;serverid=2:type=user;username=foo;password=bar;role=DBManager
```

I hope this will help.